# Under what conditions does a background process typically kill itself?

Tags: c#, windows, printing, process

Besides the main process not being active any longer

Comment: The operating system killing idle processes would be a fairly awful idea, as would not allowing a program to terminate if it wanted to, don't you think?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Welcome to [the new rules for managed apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) (i.e. Windows Store apps, Android views are similar, etc)

Comment: Suspending the application with state is somewhat different than killing a process though.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: I am talking about killing a process.  "Windows attempts to keep as many suspended apps in memory as possible. By keeping these apps in memory, Windows ensures that users can quickly and reliably switch between suspended apps. However, if there aren't enough resources to keep your app in memory, **Windows can terminate your app. Note that apps don't receive notification that they are being terminated**, so the only opportunity you have to save your app's data is during suspension"

Comment: I was responding to your asking if it was possible that a program can kill itself if it's not being used - and I'd argue that it's a terrible idea that a general purpose OS decide on whims to *kill* processes. However, as @BenVoit pointed out, this is the case for Windows Store apps, but even there there is a suspended state with programmable hooks that apps must go into before they are outright terminated.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I can't see how that would be a terrible idea. Maybe the OS can also have some settings that would let the user determine whether or not a specific process can run for a long time without being killed. All i'm saying is basically that there be a timeout on processes unless indicated otherwise by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if the OS kills a process if it's not being actively used after a while

The operating system won't kill an idle process.*

> or if it is possible that a program can kill itself after a while if its not being used?

This is likely what's occurring.

The best option is likely to create the print sessions when you need them, and destroy them in between.  Instead of trying to keep it alive for long periods of time, just create a new print session, print to it, then close it each time you need it.

---

*Note: Windows 8 Store applications have different rules here.  Given that you're using this print server, I'm fairly certain that doesn't apply.  However, a Windows 8 Store App can get suspended, and potentially terminated, by the operating system if it's left idle.

Comment: That's currently what i'm doing right now but I'm trying to optimize it so I don't create a new printer each time.

Comment: @OsatoGuobadia Creating the printer shouldn't be a bottleneck, especially if you're feeding it large TIFFs... I wouldn't worry about optimizing away something that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Osato: How are you spawning the printer process?  It's straightforward to detect if a process you spawned is still active, or to receive a notification when it terminates.

Comment: @BenVoigt `PNSrv9` is a COM component - I'd suspect it's just creating an instance of the print session via COM (which in turn will spawn the process, as it's an out of process COM server).

Comment: @Reed: Then he should be able to keep it alive via COM reference counts.

Comment: @BenVoigt IIRC that COM component will actually kill itself (which is very odd behavior) after very long periods of inactivity.  It behaves a bit oddly, which is, I suspect, why this question came up in the first place.

Comment: @Reed: If the `IUnknown` component goes away while the reference count is non-zero, it's not COM.  If the component is still around but its helper gets closed to save resources, presumably it ought to be able to start a new helper as needed.  All as internal implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

The process is likely ending iteself, as designed, due to going idle or not receiving some expected communication.  I think this is the case because Googling your exe name [showed this cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://wp.kibeom.aborg.com/category/general-faqs/product-licensing-and-activation/) with the text:

> 1. Stop your application
> 2. Open Task Manager and wait 5 minutes for *PNSrv9.exe* to disappear from the Processes list

And no, Windows does not terminate idle processes.

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows does not kill idle processes.